# why is the distribution of cosine of the angle uniform in a π0→2γ decay?

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-spin

[image: setup]

the condition is as the picture suggests. When calculating kinematics, we used a condition that the distribution of cos(θ) is uniform since the spin of `\pi^0` is 0. Why does spin 0 leads to that distribution of angle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key point is that the distribution of the emitted photons in the center of mass frame is isotropic, so each element of solid angle around the decaying $\pi^{0}$ has an equal probability of containing the trajectory of a photon. An isotropic distribution, it turns out, is one which is uniformly distributed in $\cos{\theta}$ (which is true no matter how you orient the axis to measure your $theta$ from

The quickest way to see this is to consider the solid angle subtended by a ring of radius $r$ from $\theta$ to $\theta+d\theta$. The area of the ring is $2\pi r^{2} \sin{\theta} d\theta$, the area of the whole spherical shell of radius r is $4\pi r^{2}$, so

$d\Omega=2\pi\sin{\theta}d\theta = -2\pi\ d\cos{\theta}$

($d\cos{\theta} = dX$ with $X=\cos{\theta}$, i.e. using $\cos{\theta}$ as the variable). This is linear in $\cos{\theta}$.

Comment: oh, thanks. I see... the cosine comes from the solid angle